# How can dynamically move scroll bar in gridview

Tags: android

I am using grid view for images,first time i using 16 images display in gridview after i will add another 16 images in grid view,now totally 32 images in gridview,ok now i want to move scroll bar last 16 images position in grid view,how can dynamically scroll bar in grid view?,anybody know please give code..

Thanks All

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [smoothScrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)) method to "smoothly scroll to the specified adapter position."

```
gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: @Thanks Brain,I can't add this method for gridview,

Comment: The smoothScrollToPosition method is an API Level 8 method, so you have to set your Project Target Build to Android 2.2 (API Level 8) or higher.  It will not work on older versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to force your application to use API level 8. So you can support other phones. Use:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection(int)

```
gridView.setSelection(position);
```